# how should I fetch the google api responses, from directly frontend or going through backend?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, frontend

I'm trying to find the best palace to use google API calls. Since we are using Google Maps in the front end we can call the service(distance API) directly from the front end. But we can use those services from the backend and send the response to the front end as well.

What would be the best approach? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I bet on Backend.

You will have to use Google API key and backend is the best place to save the secrets.

Comment: In the front end also we have store the secret to load the map

Comment: when we load the map we need to provide the google map API key in the HTML file, are you suggesting to get it from the backend when application start?